# Get iframe height when opening it as a jquery modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I want to show an iframe via modal popup. Here is my code:

```
$.modal('<iframe src="../_userctrlwrappers/mypage.aspx" width="360" style="border: 0;">',
            {
                escClose: true,
                opacity: 75
            });
```

How can I detect the height of mypage.aspx so that I could have its value to pass it to `$.modal`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the contentheight on load of iframe. i guess you also need to show the popup on load of this iframe.

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
this.style.height =
this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
});
```

Comment: But I want it to pass it to $.Modal, actually before the iframe is being loaded

Comment: The iframe will not be loaded until $.modal is being called

Comment: It is not possible to do that as you will not come to know the iframe height unless it loads.